# Failed Installing linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64

Tags: linux, debian

I always get this error messages when doing the command `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
> apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  owncloud owncloud-3rdparty owncloud-app-activity owncloud-app-external owncloud-app-files
  owncloud-app-files-external owncloud-app-files-locking owncloud-app-files-pdfviewer
  owncloud-app-files-sharing owncloud-app-files-texteditor owncloud-app-files-trashbin
  owncloud-app-files-versions owncloud-app-files-videoviewer owncloud-app-firstrunwizard
  owncloud-app-gallery owncloud-app-provisioning-api owncloud-app-templateeditor
  owncloud-app-user-external owncloud-app-user-ldap owncloud-app-user-webdavauth
  owncloud-config-apache owncloud-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 17.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 51164 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 (using .../linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64_3.2.68-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64_3.2.68-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/char/tpm/tpm_tis.ko' to '/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/char/tpm/tpm_tis.ko.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64_3.2.68-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


> df -h
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    322M  231M   75M  76% /
udev                       10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     368M  236K  368M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/webmail-root  322M  231M   75M  76% /
tmpfs                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                     736M     0  736M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                 228M   20M  197M  10% /boot
/dev/mapper/webmail-home  898G   13G  840G   2% /home
/dev/mapper/webmail-tmp   368M   12M  338M   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/webmail-usr   8.3G  1.3G  6.6G  17% /usr
/dev/mapper/webmail-var   2.8G  1.5G  1.2G  56% /var
/dev/mapper/webmail-home  898G   13G  840G   2% /opt

> uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

I'm trying to fix it but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because of a too small root paritition (`/`) as the message states: `No space left on device`.

75 MB appear to be not enough to unpack and install the kernel.

The easiest solution would be to free up space on the root partition or increase the size of it.

To free up space you could try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Also check if there are old kernel still on your hard drive which could also be removed.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Keep in mind to only remove those which you don't use.

Comment: Hi @ap0 , thanks for the feedback. How can i resize my root is it possible?

Comment: @JizzomaruXavier take a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67095/how-can-i-expand-ext4-partition-size-on-debian